Call a function on a `VyperContract` in titanoboa
I have the following Vyper smart contract:
from snekmate.auth import ownable as ow
initializes: ow

from snekmate.tokens import erc20
initializes: erc20[ownable := ow]

@deploy
@payable
def __init__():
    erc20.__init__("my_token", "MT", 18, "my_token_dapp", "0x02")
    ow.__init__()

And I'm initializing it as such:
from src import MyToken

usdc: VyperDeployer = MyToken.at(<USDC_ADDRESS>)

Why am I unable to call the decimals function, or any function on the usdc: VyperContract?

The issue arises because the contract MyToken does not expose any external runtime function. Titanoboa is hence not able to call any function on it and fails with  AttributeError: 'VyperContract' object has no attribute 'decimals'
In Vyper, @external functions are not automatically exposed (i.e., included in the runtime code) in the importing contract. To do so, one must use the exports statement. For more details, see https://docs.vyperlang.org/en/stable/using-modules.html#exporting-functions.
In the case of snekmate's ERC20, the library's mock contract erc20_mock.vy shows how this can be achieved, see:
https://github.com/pcaversaccio/snekmate/blob/846d2ec236c061aee2fd342a8c2a29d4f06e15d6/src/snekmate/tokens/mocks/erc20_mock.vy#L45-L60
which contains:
exports: erc20.__interface__

After updating the Vyper contract to include the missing exporting statement, the following script prints 6.
import boa
boa.env.fork(url="https://eth.llamarpc.com")
USDC_ADDRESS = "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48"
my_token = boa.load_partial("my_token.vy")
usdc = my_token.at(USDC_ADDRESS)
print(usdc.decimals())

